# How can I wrap a js chart libray inside of a React function component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this js code that I want to create a Reactjs function component for:

```
const myChart = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
    width: 300,
    height: 600,
    localization: {
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        locale: 'en-US',
    },
    timeScale: {
        //visible: true,
        timeVisible: true,
        secondsVisible: true,
    },
});
const candlestickSeriesMyChart = myChart.addCandlestickSeries();


connection.onmessage = function (event) {
    // ....
    candlestickSeriesMyChart.update({ time: tickTimeMinutes, open: json.minutes.o, high: json.minutes.h, low: json.minutes.l, close: json.minutes.p });
}


<div id="myChart"></div>
```

There is a websocket connection that will keep sending messages, and for each message I call `.update(...)` to update my chart.

How can I wrap this inside of a Reactjs function component, what thing I am not sure of is that I don't want to re-render my component each time a websocket message is received to update my chart.

How do you handle this scenerio with Reactjs?
Is that was a `Ref` is for?  I have seen this in another codebase but unsure of its use case.

```
export function MyChart(props: ChartProps) {

     
    return (
      <div className='chart'>
        <div id="myChart"></div>        
      </div>
    );
  }
```

My App will contain this component, and App.tsx will also make the websocket connection so I will need to pass MyChart a message each time it is received, and make sure it doesn't re-render the component each time...

```
<MyChart ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you'd want to use a ref to get access to the DOM element, to pass to your lib.

```
const MyChart = ({ update }) => {
   const ref = useRef()
   useEffect(() => {
        const myChart = LightweightCharts.createChart(ref.current);
        const series = myChart.addCandlestickSeries();
        return () => {
            // cleanup third party lib
        }
   }, [])
   return <div>
         <div ref={ref}></div>
       </div>
}
```

As for updating that chart without a re-render there's probably a lot of ways to go about this.

We could add a callback function that executes in the child after lib init, and leave the method of doing something with this instance up to the parent:

```
const MyApp = () => {
    const myRef = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        callChild = () => myRef.current && myRef.current.update(...)
    }, [])

    return <MyChart initCallback={(instance) => {
        // do something with the instance
        // maybe store it in another ref or state
        myRef.current = instance
        // or we could bind our message handlers directly in here
    }} />
}
```

But storing data from the child in the parent like this kind of has a code smell.

I'm not sure what pattern is best here. I would consider passing the socket down to the `Chart` component, or if we want reusability of a core Chart component, creating a `SocketChart` wrapper. That `SocketChart` could have message transformer props that helps adjust it per context.

PS: I see that chart lib has a React version.

Comment: The chart lib react version is not available to the public, they have to approve you.
I will have multiple charts on the screen potentially, can I still share the socket connection to multiple charts?

Comment: Yeah that sounds clean! Each chart can add its own socket.addEventListener() (and clean up, too) and parse out the messages its supposed to listen to. Now that's beautiful encapsulation of concerns!

Comment: Not sure how I can share a websocket with multiple components... is that like a pass by reference in javascript?

Comment: @Blankman yeah objects are passed by reference. the websocket connection can be passed around, and event listeners added from anywhere. I mean another pattern I see online is having a socket.ts file and export the connection there -- consume it anywhere. Don't love it _personally_ vs props but it seems there are many camps on this one.